# Python progress bar for RDS Snapshot copy

Tags: python, progress-bar, boto3, rds

If this question has already been asked before please let me know where, for the life of me I can't find any answer to this.

```
def waitforsnapshot(TargetDBSnapshot):
    available = False
    while not available:
    time.sleep(10)
    response_ncali_snap = get_dest_snap(ncali_client, 'testdb', 'manual')
    for i in response_ncali_snap:
        if i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'] == TargetDBSnapshot:
            print("{}: {}...".format(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'], i['Status']))
            if i['Status'] == "available":
                available = True
                break
```

I am moving RDS snapshots from one region to another, and the above code keeps working till the status changes to 'available'. I am trying to add a progress bar instead of printing the status `print("{}: {}...".format(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'], i['Status']))` every time till the snapshot status changes to available. Is there a way to do so using tqdm or another library?

Comment: Are you using EC2 or S3? If you use S3Transfer you can use a callback to get the progress. [See the docs with example progress code](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html). Based on the provided code, I can’t see how you actually trasfer the data. What type of object does get_dest_snap return? An EC2 snapshot object? If so, can’t you use the [snapshot progress](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Snapshot.progress) property?

Comment: @agtoever I am sorry if I was not clear enough, I did mention it in the topic of the question - this is when copying RDS snapshots from one region to another. 
get_dest_snap is just returning the dict of snapshots present in the region where it is being copied basically it is describe_db_snapshots and orders them by snapshot creation time.

Answer (score 0):

you could pool `DescribeDBSnapshots` [API result](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBSnapshots.html) ([method in boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_snapshots)), get progress from `PercentProgress` field, then add process bar using `tdqm` is a trivial task.

Comment: As strange as this may sound, but until the snapshot's status changes to 'available' the PercentageProgress field shows 1% and as soon as it becomes available it changes to 100%. it doesn't increment to anything above 1% until it is completed and i.e 100%. I can't paste the entire output due to limit on the comments.

Comment: @shabbzy how it goes?

Comment: Well, could not figure it, and am printing just the wait for now. Also I opened a ticket with aws, haven't heard back from them

Comment: it is sad that answered your question but the problem not resolved.